# How do I transfer information into another worksheet with a for each loop

Tags: excel, vba

Im a rather beginner with programming and wanted to ask how I code to pass information from one worksheet to another but only when a condition is met. In my case i have a list of names with their respective jobs. I want to transfer the names to another worksheet but only if the job is X. Since name and surname are in different columns but same row, I also have to find a way of selecting the row in which the job name is.

```
For Each Candidate In Sheets("XX").Range("A2:A")
    If Candidate = "Job" Then
       'Copy Name in that same row to Sheets("Job").Range("A" & next free row)
       'Copy Surname in that same row to Sheets("Job").Range("B" & next free row)

    End If
Next Candidate
```

Comment: Post your code eplease

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub transfer_information()
Dim myCell As Range
Dim target As Range
Dim colOffset As Integer
Dim TargetSheetString As String
Dim TargetWorkbookString As String

TargetSheetString = "target worksheet name goes here"
TargetWorkbookString = "target workbook name goes here"

'Uncomment to run with the the active workbook and sheet
'TargetSheetString = ActiveSheet.Name
'TargetWorkbookString = ThisWorkbook.Name

Set target = Workbooks(TargetWorkbookString).Worksheets(TargetSheetString).Range("E2") 'or whatever address
For Each myCell In Range("A1:A100")  'alter 100 as appropriate
    colOffset = 2
     If myCell.Offset(0, colOffset) = "target job" Then
         target = myCell
         target.Offset(0, 0) = myCell.Offset(0, 0)
         target.Offset(0, 1) = myCell.Offset(0, 1)
         target.Offset(0, 2) = myCell.Offset(0, 2)
         Set target = target.Offset(1, 0)
     End If
Next myCell
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assume name is in columns A and B and job in column C

```
  Dim R as Range
  dim target as range
  set target = Worksheets("target worksheet name goes here").range("a1") 'or whatever address
  For each r in RAnge("A1:A100")  'alter 100 as appropriate
       if r.offset(0,2) = "target job" then
           target = r
           target.offset(0,1) = r.offset(0,1)
           set target = target.offset(1,0)
       end if
  next r
```

Comment: You're only copying things around in the same worksheet. You never use *target*

Comment: whoops - i forget to edit t to target - thanks for spotting it